# Windows dual ubuntu startup 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-xp

Using windows XP. Used dual boot. It got stuck at startup. Got error message 255 memory for 256mb required.  I went ahead anyway. Using a gateway with 256 memory.

Do I need to install more memory for the one missing mb? Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) it requires significantly less memory. 256mb is unusable with the default desktop manager Unity.